How do I persist my app settings in late 2024?
I am trying to create my first Android app in Android Studio using Kotlin. After successfully creating a couple of activities while learning how to use Jetpack Compose, I am now the point to add a settings screen where users can toggle a couple of options.
I would like to persist these settings so they are restored after the app has been shut down and relaunched.

So, I started looking for information on how to save settings in Android apps, and it seemed like the built-in SharedPreferences type was the way to go. But SharedPreferences has been deprecated in favour of "DataStore".
So DataStore it is, it appeared. To use it, I had to add some dependency to the Gradle file, then I could start using the type PreferencesDataStore - but wait, this is deprecated, as well. The documentation says I should use the "AndroidX Preference Library" instead.
So I have to use AndroiX Preferences. But beside giving no indication of where to start, it appears this now mixes the settings UI and the action of persisting the settings. But I have already prepared my settings UI with Jetpack Compose ... so this doesn't seem to be a direct replacement of a mere preferences saving API?!

What is the default way of persisting my app settings, based on what is or is not deprecated and stable in late 2024?

"But SharedPreferences has been deprecated in favour of "DataStore"" -- no, they have not. Google is recommending DataStore, but SharedPreferences have not been deprecated.

To expand on that, SharedPreferences has a Java API. DataStore, on the other hand, supports many Kotlin features like coroutines and flows and is therefore more easy to use and integrates better in a modern app architecture. Although not technically deprecated SharedPreferences is no longer state of the art.

Your second option is the way to go. You mistakenly used PreferencesDataStore, but the documentation only talks about preferencesDataStore (note the lower case of the first character). That is not a type, it is a function which returns a DataStore, and it is not deprecated.
A sample data store implementation could look like this:
private val Context.dataStore by preferencesDataStore("settings")

private val Keys = object {
    val EXAMPLE_SETTING_1 = intPreferencesKey("example_setting_1")
    val EXAMPLE_SETTING_2 = stringPreferencesKey("example_setting_2")
}

class SettingsDataStoreManager(context: Context) {
    private val dataStore = context.dataStore

    val exampleSetting1: Flow<Int> = dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[Keys.EXAMPLE_SETTING_1] ?: 0
        }

    val exampleSetting2: Flow<String> = dataStore.data
        .map { preferences ->
            preferences[Keys.EXAMPLE_SETTING_2] ?: ""
        }

    suspend fun setExampleSetting1(value: Int) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[Keys.EXAMPLE_SETTING_1] = value
        }
    }

    suspend fun setExampleSetting2(value: String) {
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[Keys.EXAMPLE_SETTING_2] = value
        }
    }
}

This represents a single data store that could contain any number of settings (it currently only contains exampleSetting1 and exampleSetting2). Place all of this in a dedicated Kotlin file.
If you want to create another data store for the same app create a new file. Use another class name and another paramter for preferencesDataStore.

The next step would be to retrieve the exampleSetting flows in your view model and expose them as StateFlows (by using stateIn) to your composables where they can be converted to Compose State objects by calling collectAsStateWithLifecycle on them. The State will automatically update (and then trigger a recomposition) when the value in the data store is changed. Your UI will therefore always be automatically up-to-date.

Oh, good point. Unfortunately, the preferencesDataStore identifier cannot yet be resolved here. I presume I'm facing a similar issue as what was described in another question, though none of the solutions from there seem to work. Still investigating that before accepting this answer.

It's in the gradle dependency androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-android (current stable version is 1.1.1), and you need this import statement in your Kotlin file: import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore

Hm, nope. The dependency is added in builds.gradle.kts, but androidx.datastore seems to be unknown (Android Studio also highlights the datastore in import androidx.datastore.preferences.preferencesDataStore in red with a popup saying "Unresolved reference: datastore").

Have you added it to the correct gradle file, the one of the module where you want to use it? Did you do a successful gradle sync afterwards?

Aha! "gradle sync" was the missing part - apparently, this ecosystem's equivalent of npm install / nuget restore. With that, androidx.datastore etc. is found, but ApplicationContext, Singleton, and Inject are still unknown identifiers. It appears your example is using a dependency injection framework called "Hilt" (?), which requires the inclusion of several plugins and a change to the application class. This seems like a bit of overkill for my case of literally just saving 8 boolean values. So, I'll try to simplify that a bit, then I'll come back and accept once it works. Thanks!

Oh you're right. I removed it, just make sure you only ever create a single instance of SettingsDataStoreManager (which previously was guaranteed when using Hilt).
